# Python - Parsing text - Cut everything after a word

Tags: python, string, file, parsing

I've got this huge TXT file with different columns number.

```
jero, kor@gmail.com, 44d448e4d, team, 0, 6, 5, 2, s, s, s, none, none
jader, lda@gmail.com, d44a88x, team, 0, none, 48, 95, oled
etc for 15000 lines
```

I would like to cut everything after the "team" word, in each-line. I've tryied several regex but couldn't succeed.

Thank you !

Comment: I would stay away from regex. Alfie's answer seems promising

Comment: To put it another way: you want to preserve the first three columns?  Every current answer which splits or substitutes on `team` will fail if someone's email address is `mad_murdock@a_team.org`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to user regex for this, there is a straight forward solution.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        i = line.split('team')[0] + "team"
```

Comment: Excellent, it's working ! Thank you a lot.
I can't give you my upvote because I'm a total rookie in here but I'f you have Facebook or Twitter, I'll be glad to give you a follow.

Best

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're about to parse a CSV file, let's use the [dedicated module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

for row in csv.reader(your_file, skipinitialspace=True):
    if 'team' in row:
        row = row[:row.index('team')+1]
    print ', '.join(row)
```

This saves you from all the hassle with inputs like `jero_team, kor@team.com, 44d448e4d, team, 0, one_more, team, 5, 2`

Comment: You can also use `del` statement: `del row[row.index('team') + 1:]`

Comment: @falsetru: sure, a better idea would be to use `try-except pass` instead of `if` to avoid scanning the list twice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expression. Using [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> line = 'jero, kor@gmail.com, 44d448e4d, team, 0, 6, 5, 2, s, s, s, none, none'
>>> a, sep, _ = line.partition('team')
>>> a
'jero, kor@gmail.com, 44d448e4d, '
>>> sep
'team'
>>> a + sep
'jero, kor@gmail.com, 44d448e4d, team'
```

---

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, sep, _ = line.partition('team')
        line = a + sep
        # Do something with line
```

**UPDATE**

To address the problem @DSM mentioned: split on other field that contains `team`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, sep, _ = line.partition(', team,')
        line = a + sep
        # Do something with line
```